# Preventing navigation when changing react-navigation params

Tags: react-native, localization, redux, react-navigation

I have tabnavigator that has nested stacknavigators in them and when I change one of the tabnavigators screens params it navigates to that tab (change happens in componentWillReceiveProps using redux value that tells it to update). Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? If not then how would you suggest doing title that updates when I change react-native-localization language?

[Image of unwanted navigation behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRSGn.png)

```
setLanguage (language) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('@Language', language)
        .then(() => {
            Localization.setLanguage(language)
            this.props.setLocalization(Localization)
        })
    }  

setLocalization: (localization) => dispatch(SettingsActions.setLocalization(localization))
```

And on component it navigates to but I don't want it to navigate to

```
static navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        title: Localization.events_2
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.localization && nextProps.localization.language !==
    this.props.localization.language) {
        const {setParams} = this.props.navigation
        setParams({ title: nextProps.localization.events_2 })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include picture regarding to behaviour of your problem. And please include some code related to your problem

Comment: https://github.com/aajiwani/react-navigation-aware-helper

You can try this, I have created to simplify this params problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the behaviour by changing the params when user navigates to the tab instead of when the language is changed.